# How to launch my downloader app when chrome encounters a download link on android?

Tags: android, android-intent, download

I am making a download manager app. I need an activity (assume `MainActivity`) to popup when user is trying to download a file from his default browser (say chrome).

Basically I need to grab a download from chrome.

How to do this?

Comment: This is not possible. Chrome manages downloads internally.

Comment: But some popular download manager apps like ADM, IDM etc. does this

Comment: You will have to check which intents you have to add to your app which will let all other apps know what your app is capable of and which activity to launch when the user selects your app to manage the download

Comment: Download one of those "working" apps` APK, use http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk to extract it, look at the manifest file and see what intent filters/data tags they have added to their app